# Xcode: UINavigationController in a subview

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm new in Xcode (and also here, in stack overflow) and I'm trying to build an application which contains a small UINavigationController (with a TableView inside) on the top of the window. So it should not be in full screen, it's just a little part of the GUI (just like a textField, or any other kind of component).

I've read that UINavigationController is designed to be displayed on the entire screen, but would it be possible to do it anyway?

If I can't, I'll probably have to write my own UINavigationController-like and TableViewController-like, with all transition effect (between 2 TableView) etcetera...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution in a book and it's quite simple. I have to create the UINavigationViewController programmatically:

```
tableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
navCtrl = [[NavigViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
[navCtrl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 150, 200)];   
[window addSubview:navCtrl.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```